# HTML5 canvas compositing arithmetic does not agree with Porter-Duff model

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, porter-duff

I'm trying to use alpha blending with the HTML5 canvas. While the colors seem roughly OK to the eye, examining the actual pixel values with `context.getImageData()` shows discrepancies from the standard Porter-Duff model that seem far too large to be explained by the limitations of 8-bit arithmetic.

Here's the summary:

1. Read a blank canvas => `R=G=B=A=0`. This is a bit strange. Since my unpainted canvas shows up as pure white, I would have expected `R=G=B=255`. Of course, with `A=0`, the R, G, and B are irrelevant anyway. Nonetheless, I'm not sure how `R=G=B=A=0` displays as pure white.
2. Paint over it with `R=200,G=B=0,A=0.75`. Read the result as `R=201,G=B=0,A=0.75`. The `A=0.75` seems correct; Porter-Duff want `A_final=.75+(.25*0)=.75`. The `G=B=0` is fine too. But I believe the R should be `R=(.75*200)+(0*(.75-1)*0)=150`. Clearly `150 != 201`. Instead, they seem to have used the equation `Final_color=new_color` for R, G and B.
3. Paint over it again with `R=100,G=200,B=0,A=0.2`. Read the result as `R=175,G=50,B=0,A=0.8`. Again, the A computations seem correct; `.2+(1-.2)*.75=.8`. However, Porter-Duff predicts `R=(.2*100)+(.75*(1-.2)*201)=(.2*100)+(.6*201)=141`. Again, clearly `141 != 175`. Green is similarly inconsistent. However, both R and G are explained by the formula `Final_color=.25*new_color+.75*old_color` -- which unfortunately is not what Porter-Duff blending predicts.

A few other notes:

- I've presented all alpha values above as being in the range [0,1] for simplicity. Of course, getImageData actually returns them in [0,255].
- I've checked [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_srcin), and it seems to agree with me as far as what the canvas *should* do.
- I've tried both Chrome V37 and IE V11 with essentially the same results.
- Painting with `A=0` works fine, as does painting with `A=1`.
- I found a [2011 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692822/invalid-blending-results-across-all-browsers-with-html5-canvas) that complains of similar issues, but believes it is a browser bug. I have a hard time believing such a blatant bug would still remain three years later -- to appear identically in two different browsers.

Here are the code details for how I did the reading:

```
pixels=(context.getImageData (10,10,1,1)).data; console.log(pixels);
```

And the writing:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc (10,10, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(200,0,0,.75)";
context.fill ();
```